# Preserving read-only flags in Mercurial (or equivalent)

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs, readonly

We'd like to prevent changes to SQL migration scripts that are in source control and have already been applied. Is there a way to mark files (specifically, SQL migration scripts) as read-only and persist this in source control?

We could resort to pre-commit hooks in our central repository, but this would require users to perform some advanced mercurial operations to undo their local commits.

Failing that, any other suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [AclExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/AclExtension).  It allows you to specify access controls in a variety of ways.

In your case, you could try making the scripts "read-only" by disallowing all changes to those files for all users (see the `DONT-TOUCH-THIS.txt` example).

Note that this still requires a hook, but at least saves you the trouble of writing one yourself.  You could have all developers agree to use the `pretxncommit` hook, which prevents a commit transaction from taking place if the ACL permissions are violated.